# WebdriverIO screenshot fails after waiting for execute condition

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I'm trying to write a very simple WebdriverIO script that will hit a URL, wait for some condition to be true in JS (e.g. a global variable being set) and take a screenshot once it is true. But `waitUntil` is throwing up with an error saying "CommandError: Promise never resolved with an truthy value". Below is a simplified version of my script:

```
"use strict";

var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var client = webdriverio.remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
    },
})
.init()
.url("https://google.com")
.waitUntil(
    function() {
        return client.execute(
            function() {
                return true;
            }
        );
    }
)
.screenshot();
```

My actual condition will of course be more than just "`return true;`", but this shows an execution that obviously will return a truthy value.

If I remove the call to `screenshot()`, then no error appears.

I've tried setting a high timeout value for `waitUntil()`, and I've tried returning the actual result.value from the `.execute()` call--neither have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, on a hunch I tried something. Instead of calling `client.execute()`, I called `this.execute()`. For some reason, that worked. My only guess as to the reason is that waitUntil executes itself in a special context that is separate from `client`, and that context is what it expects a promise on somehow.